# Navigating back to flutter app from external app doesent work on iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I have a flutter app which launches an url that opens an external application which automatically starts a task. I want the app to return to the flutter app after it has completed its task. This seems to work automatically on android, but on iOS it stays on the external app and i have to manually switch.

Is there a way for this to work on iOS aswell?

Here is my code for launching the external app:

`launchUrl(Uri.parse(uri), webOnlyWindowName: "_blank", mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);`